# Botão "Go Live" não aparece no meu Vs Code após instalar o Live Server

Tags: visual-studio-code

Fiz a instalação da extensão "Live Server" no meu VsCode, porém o botão "Go Live" não aparece. Já reiniciei meu VsCode e até tentei instalar outras versões dessa extensão, porém sem sucesso. Como faço para "habilitar" esse botão?

Answer (score -1):

Olá. Verifique se essa barrinha está aparecendo no seu VS [image: Exemplo]

Caso não esteja aparecendo,você deverá acessar View -> Appearance --> e clicar em "Show Status Bar"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fazendo isso o Go Live vai aparecer.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No meu VsCode aparece sim essa barrinha ao qual você informou. Tentei até instalar a extensão do Live Server em outra máquina para testar, porém ainda não aparece essa opção do "Go Live". Não sei se posso estar fazendo algo de errado, mas instalação de extensões no VsCode é relativamente simples.